# dmraid/LVM Boot Issues After Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lvm, boot, ubuntu-18.04, dmraid

I am experiencing an issue with dmraid/LVM after upgrading one Ubuntu 16.04 machine to 18.04. The root file system of this machine is located on a LVM LV on a RAID 1 consisting of two disks realized using dmraid.

The boot process is dropping into a initramfs BusyBox shell after the upgrade. After some investigation I realized that the RAID 1 set is not activated during the boot process. Consequently, LVM sees two different disks with the same LVM PV ID. LVM refuses to activate the PV while it appears on multiple devices and, in consequence, the root file system located on a LV on the non-activated PV is missing.

[image: Boot Screen. PV and server names removed, important lines highlighted.]

I was able to boot the system by manually activating the RAID 1 set and by telling LVM to ignore the individual hard disks:

```
dmraid -ay
lvm vgchange -ay --config 'devices { filter = [ "r|/dev/sd.*|" ] }'
exit
```

However, this is just a workaround and I would like to find a proper solution for these issues.

## Edit #1 (2020/01/02)

Output of `cat /proc/partitions` as requested:

[image: cat /proc/partitions]

The output of `dmesg` [can be accessed here](https://pastebin.com/VyKmTDEn).

Comment: Look into the system logs with `journalctl -b` and search to see why the dmraid is not detected.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici Unfortunately, `journalctl -b` does not bring up any related information to dmraid/raid.

Comment: Could you please run `dmesg` in the busybox shell and attach the output? Also run `cat /proc/partitions` or, better, if exists in busybox, `lsblk`.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici Output of `dmesg` and `cat /proc/partitions` has been posted as Edit #1 to the original question. `lsblk` is not available in the BusyBox shell.

Answer (score 0):

Update the filter configuration in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to apply the configuration at runtime.

Comment: I tried this already, but it seems that this configuration is completely ignored. Neither the boot process nor the LVM tools on the normal running system respect the filter configuration. Additionally, the dmraid issue would not be solved just by using an LVM device filter.

Comment: Try again to boot the system manually, backup /etc, then try to uninstall, then re-install mdadm.